# Find joint density given conditional density

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expected-value, joint-distribution, exponential-distribution

[image]

**These are the steps I followed:**

$ \frac{f(y_1,y_2)}{f(y_1)} = f(y_2|y_1) $

$ f(y_1,y_2) = f(y_1).f(y_2|y_1) $

$ f(y_1,y_2) = 3e^{-3y_1}.\frac{1}{2y_1} = \frac{3}{2y_1} e^{-3y_1}$

Inorder to find marginal distribution of y2, we need to integrate wrt y1 from 0 to infinity.

But this integral has **no bounded solution** from what I know. Is there something I'm missing or some transformation that I should be doing somewhere?

Comment: You are missing the indicator function $\mathbb I_{0\le y_2\le y_1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question asks you to use the conditional distribution. You'll utilise the law of total expectation:

$$E[Y_2]=E[E[Y_2|Y_1]]$$

And, $E[Y_2|Y_1]=Y_1$.